# How to pass user instance to a view in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-users

I am making a blog app where I want to make a view that displays all the blogs of a particular user. For this I need to pass the user instance to my view as

```
def blogs(request,author=None,slug=None):

   # If the author context has been passed then display the blogs of that author 
   if author:

        # Displays a particular blog
        if slug:         
            this_blog = get_object_or_404(Entry, creator = author, slug = slug)
            return render_to_response('blog/blog_view.html', {'blog': this_blog,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        # Displays all the blogs of a particular user
        else:
            blog_list = Entry.objects.filter(creator = author)
            return render_to_response('blog/all_blogs_user.html', {'Blogs': blog_list},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Although syntactically this is correct but now I do not how to actually pass this user context in my url. Earlier I tried passing just the user id but that does not work. Is there any other alternative to doing this thing. When I am building the url internally or redirecting to this particular view then it is fine, but how would the url look like externally. My urls.py is as

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'blog.views.blogs', name='all_blogs'),
    url(r'^(?P<author>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'blog.views.blogs', name='view_blog'),                       
    url(r'^(?P<author>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', 'blog.views.post_form', name='edit_blog'),
    url(r'^new/$', 'blog.views.post_form', name='new_blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<author>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/delete/$', 'blog.views.delete_blog', name='delete_blog'),

)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "passing just the user id ... does not work"? What happens?

Comment: `creator` needs to be `User` instance not integer. First get the `User` by `pk` then use it in `Entry` query. `author = User.objects.get(pk=author)`

Comment: @isbadawi Actually the problem was I was able to pass the user id but I was directly referring in the filter as creator.id = author_id and that was wrong as rebus has pointed out I need to first get that obejct and then use it

Answer (score 3):

It generally works like this:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'/author/(?P<slug>/$', 'author_index'),
```

**views.py**

```
def author_index(request, slug):
    author = get_object_or_404(User, username=slug)

    return render_to_response('author_index.html', {
        'author': author,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I did not understand what you are saying... This will simply written the user whose username = slug

Comment: You get the "slug" (in this case the username) for the author from the URL. You use that to look up the corresponding `User` instance from the database. You then pass that instance into the template context in `render_to_response`. Now, in your template you can access the `author`. What's the part you're stuck on?

Comment: Actually I want to pass a list of blogs of a particular user, but I have resolved that now. Thanks alot I used rebus solution

Answer (score 2):

You can simply access the user in the view by **request.user**. Similarly, you can **POST** data in the request object as well.

Comment: Request user returns current authenticated user, so you could only ever see your own blog entries.

Comment: Yes it only returns the current user and I want to view the blogs of any user

Comment: the second option is request.POST. for example localhost/blog?user=anyuser can be used to send data. And this data can be accessed in view by request.POST.get('user','')